# Balancing covariates on binary outcome instead on treatment

Tags: causality, matching, causal-diagram

Here's the following problem, in the abstract:

- y is a binary outcome
- X are covariates
- c is a continuous treatment/exposure variable
- a and b are regression parameters
- y, X, and c are somewhat correlated empirically (but the true model does not have to be).

The GLM regression (identity link function) we estimate is thus:
y = a * c + b * X + error   (Eq. 1)

The modern solution is perhaps to pre-balance X based on the continuous c treatment á la Tübbicke. [1]

**Question**: What happens if one instead balances the covariate across the two levels of y (and run Eq. 1)? For example, could this lead to an endogenous selection bias?

---

**Example** (firm setting, made up but practical)

- y = firm is insolvent, via an indicator that they announced it
- c = revenue growth (w.l.o.g. positive growth)
- X is size, leverage, age, industry, competition, etc

Now assume the theory says low revenue growth is a precursor of announcing bankruptcy. The model above is a simple specification to test a < 0.
The covariates ought to control for observable confounders. Note that we don't know how the firms look like after they went bankrupt, we can only observe them before.

Someone in the crowd shouts: are the two groups (insolvent, solvent) comparable firms, why don't you balance the covariates so that the groups are "the same"?

Instead of dismissing them, I do think there is an intuitive or reasonable argument to be had. First, correlations are symmetrical, so it's not impossible to get inspired from a model c = y + X + error, whether that makes sense or not. Second, perhaps it's more complicated and firms self-select into a pre-treatment (insolvent but not announcing) status, so it would be nice to have balanced groups.

**Question**: I'm not looking for a complete answer or the perfect DAG, but what would be the framework that guides your answer? How should we think about it and respond to the question-asker?

---

[1] Tübbicke, S. (2022). Entropy Balancing for Continuous Treatments. Journal of Econometric Methods, 11(1), 71–89. doi:10.1515/jem-2021-0002

Comment: Suppose we believe X -> c, X -> y and c -> y. Then, balancing on X closes the causal channel between X and y. A weighted regression of y on c and X with those balancing weights will bias our estimates for c -> y because we haven't accounted for the X -> c channel

Comment: @wahid I don't think that makes sense. If $X$ and $y$ are uncorrelated (in the weighted sample), there is no confounding. Adding $X$ to a regression of $y$ on $c$ will only reduce precision but shouldn't affect bias because the $X$ are now instruments.

Comment: @Noah, thanks for pointing out that the X are now IVs. I was trying to intuit what that regression's results would say, and my instinct was that the treatment estimate wouldn't be "proper". How'd you characterize the estimate?

Comment: Keep in mind we're balancing on covariates to remove confounding. Not sure what the intent of balancing on outcome levels would be?

Comment: Thanks -- I've added a practical example. I hope it doesn't end up raising too many new questions.

Comment: If we end up nowhere in a few days, I will add some simulation results.